# Have to send exact Task DetailPage as email to Customers

Tags: email, email-template, tasks

How can I send the Detail Page of Task to Customer in the form of Email.
 I tried it by creating email templates, Workflows, Process builder but it's not similar to Detail Page.
 Using Apex trigger for Task object, we can send email to particular end user, but is not in the format as required(Requirement as shown below in the image).

How can I obtain the output as shown in the image.

[image: Output required like the image displayed]

Comment: I think you can't Send Detail view of record in the form of image..you can send details in the form of excel or else you can provide record link to client..

Comment: Actually I don't want the detail view to be sent in the form of attachments, instead I want it be viewed as we view the body of the email.

Comment: you can schedule a report and report will be in the form of screenshot send..but record page screenshot is tuff.